# LaTeX, quoting same author without numbering

Tags: bibtex

I am finishing a thesis and my bibstyle troubles me. I could not find an answer to following the question:

How can I remove the automatic numbering (a, b, c, d...) of the same author quoted several times?

My search for an answer brought me so far:
I guess it has to do with the `FUNCTION{forward.pass}`, probably with the `FUNCTION{reverse.pass}`. Because if I remove these functions (which works) the numbering is not shown any more, **BUT** (this is my problem now!) a comma and the space-sign stay. (which is annoying. because it looks like this:

Author; Title, ;URL; note. 
(the comma and the space after it should vanish.)

The way I found to solve this problem temporarily is the following:
Just edit the .bbl file - deleting what should not be there and compile once.
(This works, but is a very *un-LaTeX-y* way...)

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,]    {report}                       

\begin{document}

Test text with citation 1: \cite{ZeusFocusonPEEK.2006}. And further citations here \cite{Saib.1993,CAMPUSdaten.2012}.

\bibliographystyle{BibstyleDAAK}
\bibliography{literatur2}

\end{document}
```

and the literature2.bib

```
ï»¿@electronic{CAMPUSdaten.2012,
author = {Anonymus},
title = {{C}{A}{M}{P}{U}{S} {D}atenbank},
url = {http://www.campusplastics.com/d},
urldate = {31.10.2012}
}

@article{Saib.1993,
author = {Saib, K. S. and Evans, W. J. and Isaac, D. H.},
year = {1993},
title = {{T}he role of microstructure during fatigue crack growth in poly(aryl ether ether ketone) ({P}{E}{E}{K})},
pages = {3198--3203},
volume = {34},
number = {15},
journal = {Polymer}
}

@electronic{ZeusFocusonPEEK.2006,
author = {Anonymus},
title = {{Z}eus {F}ocus on {P}{E}{E}{K}},
url = {http://www.zeusinc.com/},
urldate = {31.10.2012}
}
```

and the BibstyleDAAK has approximately 1700 lines. I generated it with the docstrip utility.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. Though it took me some time - I was able make the minimal working example, which I included above. Further I'd like to know if there is a possibility to upload the bibstyle file otherwise I need to post the whole file right?